# How is torus(T2) # klein bottle (K2) classified? K2#K2?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

I have some problems with some exercise questions in famous book Topology of Surfaces, Kinsey.
The exercises 4.18 which states the following, "How is torus(T2) # klein bottle (K2) classified? K2#K2?"
Can you help me, i could not solve this? The sign '#' indicates the connected sum.

Comment: Do you know the classification of surfaces in terms of Euler characteristic (or genus) and orientability, and how to calculate the Euler characteristic of a connected sum in terms of the Euler characteristics of the summands?

Comment: My instructor has not teach euler characteristic yet but i know the orientability issue.

Comment: See also [Connected sum of torus and klein bottle classification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212090), which is identical, but does not yet have an answer.